# Bash array declared in a function is not available outside the function

Tags: bash, function, array

on bash (v4.3.11) terminal type this:

```
function FUNCtst() { declare -A astr; astr=([a]="1k" [b]="2k" ); declare -p astr; };FUNCtst;declare -p astr
```

(same thing below, just to be easier to read here)

```
function FUNCtst() { 
  declare -A astr; 
  astr=([a]="1k" [b]="2k" ); 
  declare -p astr; 
};
FUNCtst;
declare -p astr
```

will output this (outside of the function the array looses its value, why?)

```
declare -A astr='([a]="1k" [b]="2k" )'
bash: declare: astr: not found
```

I was expecting it output this:

```
declare -A astr='([a]="1k" [b]="2k" )'
declare -A astr='([a]="1k" [b]="2k" )'
```

how to make it work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html):

> When used in a function, declare makes each name local, as with the `local` command, unless the `-g` option is used.

Example:

```
FUNCtst() { 
    declare -gA astr
    astr=([a]="1k" [b]="2k" )
    declare -p astr
}
FUNCtst
declare -p astr
```

prints

```
declare -A astr=([a]="1k" [b]="2k" )
declare -A astr=([a]="1k" [b]="2k" )
```