# Assoc. Array not being redeclared?

Tags: bash, array, associative-array

I have a program that acts like a menu. It has an associative array called `config` such as:

```
declare -A config=( [h]="?" [c]="?" [x]="?" [l]="?" [t]="?" [n]="?" )
```

In the main loop there's a check to see if all of the values have been configured, like:

```
if [ "${config[h]}" == "Y" ] && [ "${config[c]}" == "Y" ] && [ "${config[l]}" == "Y" ] && [ "${config[x]}" == "Y" ] && [ "${config[t]}" == "Y" ] && [ "${config[n]}" == "Y" ];
```

Now, when I **finish** one run, I unset and redeclare the array.

```
unset config; declare -A config=( [h]="?" [c]="?" [x]="?" [l]="?" [t]="?" [n]="?" )
```

However, the array doesn't seem to be re-declared properly. This is because when I configure just **one** of the values, `[C]=Y` for example, the `if` statement passes. I know for sure it does because the body of the `if` statement changes some of the text color. I believe it's because the rest of the indices aren't actually set="?", so the `if` statement is reduced to just `[ "${config[c]}" == "Y"]` which is be `true`. I know this since when I echo `$config[@]` inside the body of the `if` statement, sure enough I only see **one** "Y" instead of five. How do I get the array to redeclare properly?

**EDIT**
Thank you for your attention;

1. Values are set to Y after some user input. This part I'm very confident about  and thus omitted from my question. They all follow this format:

   ```
    read ch
           if [ $ch == "Hosts" ]; then
                   while true; do
                           nano listHosts
                           echo -en "Commit this list of Hostnames? [Y|N to re-edit]: "
                           read yn
                           if [ $yn == "Y" ] || [ $yn == "y" ] || [ $yn == "yes" ]; then
                                   break
                           elif [ $yn == "N" ] || [ $yn == "n" ] || [ $yn == "no" ]; then  
                                   continue
                           fi      
                   done
                   config[h]="Y"
   ```
2. Regarding Kusalanda's comment, I checked for incorrect casing but it's consistently lower-case 'c'. As well, yes, I meant `${config[@]}`.
3. Declare -p sheds some light:
   `declare -a config='([0]="Y")'`

How come -p says I used lowercase a? The calls are in this order:

```
 unset config
 declare -A config=( [h]="?" [c]="?" [x]="?" [l]="?" [t]="?" [n]="?" )
```

Then I set $ch="Commands" via `read`;

```
 elif [ $ch == "Commands" ]; then  
                while true; do
                        nano iSet
                        echo -en "Commit this list of commands? [Y|N to re-edit]: "             
                        read yn                        
                        if [ $yn == "Y" ] || [ $yn == "y" ] || [ $yn == "yes" ]; then           
                                break
                        elif [ $yn == "N" ] || [ $yn == "n" ] || [ $yn == "no" ]; then                  
                                continue        
                        fi      
                done        
                config[c]="Y"
                declare -p config
```

I tried to recreate in a smaller script as per Bodo's suggestion:

```
dec() {
        declare -A config=( [h]="?", [c]="?" )
}
test() {
        declare -p config
        if [ "${config[h]}" == "Y" ] && [ "${config[c]}" == "Y" ]; then 
                echo "Yup"
        fi
}

dec
config[h]="Y"; config[c]="Y"

unset config
dec
config[h]="Y" 

test
```

And just like in my other script, the `if` resolves to true:
`declare -a config='([0]="Y")'
Yup`

Comment: (a) I don't see anything being set to `Y`, and (b) `$config[@]` ... Did you mean `"${config[@]}"`?

Comment: Do you mean `[c]="Y"` rather than `[C]=Y`? Also, did you mean you printed `${config[@]}` rather than `$config[@]`?

Comment: If you you `declare` a variable inside a function, it makes that variable _local to the function_.  It is an issue in the test code that you show, but we don't know whether you have the same issue in your real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare the array as global in your functions using `declare -g ...`. Otherwise the array will be a local variable **in the function**. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136721/330217

See this modified script with some debug output

```
#! /bin/bash

# set -x

dec() {
        # declare -A config=( [h]="?", [c]="?" )
        declare -gA config=( [h]="?" [c]="?" )
        echo dec: ${config[*]}
}
test() {
        declare -p config
        if [ "${config[h]}" == "Y" ] && [ "${config[c]}" == "Y" ]; then
                echo "Yup"
        else
                echo "No"
        fi
        echo test: ${config[*]}
}

dec
echo 1: ${config[*]}
config[h]="Y"; config[c]="Y"
echo 2: ${config[*]}

test

unset config
dec
echo 3: ${config[*]}
config[h]="Y"
echo 4: ${config[*]}

test
```

The output is

```
$ ./script
dec: ? ?
1: ? ?
2: Y Y
declare -A config=([c]="Y" [h]="Y" )
Yup
test: Y Y
dec: ? ?
3: ? ?
4: ? Y
declare -A config=([c]="?" [h]="Y" )
No
test: ? Y
```

When I uncomment your line and comment my modified line, the output is

```
$ ./script
dec: ? ?,
1:
2: Y
declare -a config=([0]="Y")
Yup
test: Y
dec: ? ?,
3:
4: Y
declare -a config=([0]="Y")
Yup
test: Y
```

Copied from @ilkkachu's comment:

> And of course, after the local declaration of the associative array falls out of scope, the assignment `config[h]="Y"` creates a regular array, where the index is interpreted in an arithmetic context, where `h` (recursively) expands the value of the variable `h`, which probably isn't set and you get the empty string that evaluates to zero, so it's `config[0]` that gets set. And there's no error message since `set -u` isn't in effect.

This can be seen in the output `declare -a config=([0]="Y")` from the original script.

Comment: Using the -g switch fixed this problem! Thank you.

Comment: And of course, after the local declaration of the associative array falls out of scope, the assignment `config[h]="Y"` creates a regular array, where the index is interpreted in an arithmetic context, where `h` (recursively) expands the value of the variable `h`, which probably isn't set and you get the empty string that evaluates to zero, so it's `config[0]` that gets set. And there's no error message since `set -u` isn't in effect.

Comment: @ilkkachu thank you for the in-depth insight!